# How if at all is it useful to clear cookies when clearing the cache?

Tags: cache, cookies

The Refreshyourcache site (http://www.refreshyourcache.com/) does not mention clearing cookies, and says that its instructions "to clear your browser's cache [will force] it to download all latest data from a website." Yet one is frequently advised to clear *both* cache and cookies. What if any advantage is there to clearing the cookies as well?

Comment: Is there a reason you are clearing cache and cookies? Cookies are what save your logins for sites. I usually don't clear them unless I need to, but I use CCleaner to save the ones for sites I want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are used by websites (and web based applications) to store client specific information on the client computer. If you clear your cookies then most (practically all) sites will no longer remember that you're logged in. That is usually the extent of the loss of information. Much more information could be stored in cookies but, generally, that other information is also stored in your account (which is stored in the DB on the website remote system). The next time you log in, all of that other information will be written to a new cookie for quick retrieval later. At the end of the day, web developers know that the end user has the ability to clear cookies so they treat cookie information as temporal and, as such, design their website to handle the loss of all of that information at any time without problems.

As for how useful it is to do this, well that depends on what you're doing. If you're developing a website and you want to make sure everything is working as expected then you'll find yourself doing this a lot while you develop the cookie handling portions of your site. As an end user of a website, you should never have any problems with them and should never need to worry about them. If, for some reason, you are having problems logging into or out of a website then clearing your cookies may fix the issue. Clearing you cookies may help if a particular setting you've changed on a site isn't being applied properly. These are both caused by errors in the website itself but clearing the cookies can often fix those errors by forcing the site to recreate the cookies. You're most likely to see these sort of problems if the site has recently gone through an update and the cookie handling portion of the site has changed but the system wasn't designed to log everyone out when that happened.